# Spring Integration JPA inbound channel adapter

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-integration

I have a `spring-integration` `message channel` which read from a database using a `jpa inbound-channel-adapter`.

```
<int:channel id="logChannel">
    <int:priority-queue capacity="20" />
</int:channel>

<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="logChannel" entity-class="com.objects.Transactionlog"
    entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory" auto-startup="true"
    jpa-query="SELECT x FROM Transactionlog AS x WHERE x.status LIKE '1'" max-results="1">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED"
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

This always reads only the first row of the table `transactionlog`. So I want to update the `status` of each database entry just after read. Any body know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `max-results="1"` is OK for you and receive only one entity per 5 second is appropiate for your use-case, let it be.

Now how to update that entity to skip it on the next poll.

The `<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>` has `delete-after-poll="true"` option, which allows to perform `entityManager.remove(entity)` after an entity retrival.

Right, it is the real removal from DB. To convert it to the UPDATE, you can mark your entity with:

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE Transactionlog SET status = false WHERE id = ?")
```

Or something similar, that is appropiate for you.

Another feature is [Transaction Synchronization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization), when you mark your `<poller>` with some `before-commit` factory and do UPDATE there. Something like:

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter ...>
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
      <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED"
           transaction-manager="transactionManager"
           synchronization-factory="txSyncFactory" />
    </int:poller>
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="txSyncFactory">
    <int:before-commit channel="updateEntityChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int:chain input-channel="updateEntityChannel">
   <int:enricher>
       <int:property name="status" value="true"/>
   </int:enricher>
   <int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter entity-manager="entityManager"/>
</int:chain/>
```

Something like that.