# Spring Integration JpaExecutor

Tags: spring, integration

I'd like to do update statement with `JpaExecutor` like this

```
JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(jdbcTemplate,"select * from EPAM_EVENT_STORE_T where EVENT_STATUS = 0");
adapter.setUpdateSql("update EPAM_EVENT_STORE_T set EVENT_STATUS = 1 where event_store_id in (:eventStoreId)");
```

but `JpaExecutor` doesn't have update method.

I'v seen dirty hack in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050008/does-jpapollingchanneladapter-have-similar-functionality-to-jdbcpollingchannelad) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602591/spring-integration-jpa-inbound-channel-adapter). 
But really, is it possible to do it without dirty hacks?

Comment: Why not use NativeSql o JpQL? `JpaExecutor` has the following methods:  `setJpaQuery`, `setNamedQuery`, `setNativeQuery`

Comment: Yeah, it's possible. But problem, that I need to update status in Event entity after select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is how I solved this problem.

```
@MessageEndpoint
@Log
public class MessageFromEvent {

  private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
  private final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager;

  @Autowired
  public MessageFromEvent(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory,
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
  }

  @Bean
  @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "selectEventChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000"))
  public MessageSource<?> selectEvent() {
    log.info("STEP 1: Getting data form EventStore table");
    return new JpaPollingChannelAdapter(selectEventExecutor());
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaExecutor selectEventExecutor() {
    JpaExecutor executor = new JpaExecutor(this.entityManagerFactory);
    executor.setJpaQuery("select event from Event event where event.eventStatus = 0");
    executor.setUsePayloadAsParameterSource(true);
    executor.setEntityClass(Event.class);
    return executor;
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "selectEventChannel")
  public MessageHandler updateEventStatus(JpaExecutor updateEventExecutor) {
    log.info("STEP 2: Updating event status");
    JpaOutboundGateway gateway = new JpaOutboundGateway(updateEventExecutor);
    gateway.setGatewayType(OutboundGatewayType.UPDATING);

    MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource attributeSource = new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource();
    attributeSource.setTransactionAttribute(new DefaultTransactionAttribute());
    TransactionInterceptor interceptor = new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, attributeSource);
    gateway.setAdviceChain(singletonList(interceptor));

    return gateway;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaExecutor updateEventExecutor() {
    JpaExecutor executor = new JpaExecutor(this.entityManagerFactory);
    executor.setJpaQuery("update Event E set E.eventStatus = 1 where E.eventStoreId in (:eventStoreId)");
    executor.setJpaParameters(Collections.singletonList(new JpaParameter("Event.eventStoreId", null, "payload")));
    executor.setUsePayloadAsParameterSource(true);
    executor.setEntityClass(Event.class);
    return executor;
  }
}
```